# Spring + Spring Data JPA in Java SE standalone

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, maven-assembly-plugin, jar-with-dependencies

I am trying to create a simple JAR with Spring + Spring Data + Hibernate capabilities. This  is working when I have just put Spring or Hibernate + JPA separated but not when I am putting all them together.

Is this type of configuration possible?

I am using Maven assembly plugin just to create a JAR with dependencies.

I am also indicating the concrete packages to scan the JPA entities and it works with eclipse but not when I execute the single JAR.

My configuration is XML-free (there are not persistence.xml or application.xml) and now is looking for persistence.xml. if I put the file in META-INF/persisntece.xml the error is the same.

Updated: ConfigPersistence

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=_PackageTypeSafeClassModel.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=_PackageTypeSafeClassModelRepositories.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(ConfigProperties.class)
public class ConfigPersistence {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogNames.CONFIGURATION.toString());

    /* Connection properties */ 
    @Value("${db.user}") private String propDBUser;
    @Value("${db.pass}") private String propDBPass;
    @Value("${db.host}") private String propDBHost;
    @Value("${db.port}") private String propDBPort;
    @Value("${db.database}") private String propDBDatabase;

    /* Pool properties */
    @Value("${db.pool.datasource}") private String propDatasource;
    @Value("${db.pool.setMinimumIdle}") private Integer propSetMinimumIdle;
    @Value("${db.pool.setIdleTimeout}") private Integer propSetIdleTimeout;
    @Value("${db.pool.setMaximumPoolSize}") private Integer propSetMaximumPoolSize;
    @Value("${db.pool.setConnectionTimeout}") private Integer propSetConnectionTimeout;

    /* Hibernate properties */  
    @Value("${db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}") private String propHibernateHbm2ddl;
    @Value("${db.hibernate_dialect}") private String propHibernateDialect;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.show_sql}") private String propHibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.format_sql}") private String propHibernateFormatSql;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.generate_statistics}") private String propHibernateStatistics;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.use_sql_comments}") private String propHibernateSqlComments;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.connection.autocommit}") private String propHibernateAutocommit;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.mapping.precedence}") private String propHibernatePrecedence;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory  entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(_PackageTypeSafeClassModelEntities.class.getPackage().getName());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() );
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());        
        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        HikariDataSource hikariDS = new HikariDataSource();

        /* Hikari Pool configuration */
        hikariDS.setPoolName( "HikariCP pool" );
        hikariDS.setDataSourceClassName( propDatasource );
        hikariDS.setMinimumIdle( propSetMinimumIdle );
        hikariDS.setIdleTimeout( propSetIdleTimeout );              // Minutes
        hikariDS.setMaximumPoolSize( propSetMaximumPoolSize );      // Connection pool size
        hikariDS.setConnectionTimeout( propSetConnectionTimeout );  // Miliseconds

        /* Database configuration */
        hikariDS.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propDBHost );
        hikariDS.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", propDBPort );
        hikariDS.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propDBDatabase );
        hikariDS.addDataSourceProperty("user", propDBUser );
        hikariDS.addDataSourceProperty("password", propDBPass );

        LOGGER.info("Database connection to: {}:{}, database {} with user {}", 
                propDBHost, propDBPort, propDBDatabase, propDBUser);    

        return hikariDS;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", propHibernateDialect );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", "myEntityManager");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", propHibernateHbm2ddl );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", propHibernateShowSql );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", propHibernateFormatSql  );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", propHibernateStatistics );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", propHibernateSqlComments );
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", propHibernateAutocommit );   
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.mapping.precedence", propHibernatePrecedence);

        LOGGER.info("Setting {} hibernateProperties {}", hibernateProperties.size(), hibernateProperties);      
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:591) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.company.config.ConfigPersistence.entityManagerFactory(ConfigPersistence.java:88) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.company.config.ConfigPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1e8e6cc.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1(<generated>) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.company.config.ConfigPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1e8e6cc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$17999b5a.invoke(<generated>) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.company.config.ConfigPersistence$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1e8e6cc.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:588) ~[company-monitor-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
[ERROR][CONFIGURATION] - [Main.java:30] - 24/05/2016 11:57:05.614 - Exception: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.company.config.ConfigPersistence: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
```

Updated: POM Dependencies

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Databases dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${database.oracle.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging: SL4J and LogBack dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JCommander -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>${jcommander.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I would suggest using Spring Boot to create an executable jar, saves you some headaches. Regardless can you add your `ConfigPersistence` to the question.

Comment: I am considering SpringBoot but I think it is too heavy for my current environment. Do you have any example of standalone app with SpringBoot taking into account the memory performance?

Comment: Why would that be? Why would a command line application running boot be different from running yours? Spring Boot doesn't mean you have to have tomcat or the likes, you can use if for plain command line stuff. There would be no difference. The main issue here is the fact that the modified jar has some classpath tricks in there I believe which don't fair well with the loading in  spring, so that would require some trickery. Also instead of doing assumptions about memory and performance there is only one thing you can do and that is test for yourself!

Comment: That isn't a plain command line app you also include undertow so you have a web based application.

Comment: There is not a really big difference (in memory terms) including web dependencies. For this reason, I am considering to create a Micro-service but even without this dependencies, the memory remains around 400mb-500mb

Comment: Although it shouldn't matter you shouldn't include the slf4j, logback and hibernate dependencies as those are included already for you. You have also `spring-data-jpa` included which creates proxies, so if you don't need it and have plain daos then don't include this. What would be nice is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. There is no reason that the app should take that much memory (see also https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance). which have a lot less memory even for web based apps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get a working solution using the `maven-assembly-plugin` I would suggest using Spring Boot. That will already take care of those things like setting proper class loaders etc.

Start with translating your configuration into an `application.properties` and use the [Spring Boot property names](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Then you can simply remove your configuration classes (as Spring Boot will auto detect what is on your classpath and configure accordingly).

> Although as a migration strategy you could start with your own configuration classes, get it running and then strip everything that is provided for you (which is basically everything you have shown here).

Next create a starter class (in a top-level package so that it covers all packages).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Your dependencies should look something like this. (deduced from your question but I assume there is a bit more).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That is assuming that you use Spring Boot as a parent for your project.

Instead of the assembly plugin use the spring boot plugin.

```
<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That should give you an executable jar without much effort and automatically bootstrapping your application.

Comment: Taking into account your suggestion, I am trying with Spring Boot but the memory is a really big problem. When I was working with JSE + Hibernate + Spring I was using around 50-70mb but with Spring Boot around 500mb-700mb. Any ideas to deal with Spring Boot memory and how to avoid to load everything?

Comment: How much is loaded and what is used depends on your dependencies. So without seeing your dependencies it is hard to see what is wrong.

Comment: I included the POM dependencies

Comment: As stated you have a web application not a plain command line one. You are including undertow, which triggers the start of the web related stuff. So it isn't plain Java se, hibernate and spring it is a full blown Spring mVC application (from the pov of Spring Boot bootstrapping a lot more then needed).

Answer (score 0):

According the stacktrace provided, you are using a [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) and

> LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's standard **container bootstrap** contract ([source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html))

But Spring also provide [LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) and

> LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's standard **standalone bootstrap** contract ([source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html))

So first thing to do is to use a LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean. I don't know if it will solve all your problems, but at least, it's a first step if you are not running within a container.

Comment: Good suggestion but I want to customize the Datasource and the persistence provider (hibernate) Thus, I need to use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as they indicate in their documentation

Comment: You can customize datasource and persistenceProvider with a LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean exactly as you do with a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean